# tkinter tk/toplevel execution pauses a callback's execution?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, toplevel

I have a program which requires a dialog to ask for an input string which is stored in a `global` variable; currently, I'm using a `Toplevel` window as a child of the main `Tk` window to do so.  The problem is that the `global` variable is changed (this works, I checked within a callback method), but the value isn't retained once I call `destroy` on the `Toplevel` window.

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        """initialization"""
        # widgets

        self.window = Tk()

        get_string = Button(
            self.window,
            command = self.on_get_string,
            text = "Open string"
            )

        # pack the widgets

        get_string.pack()
        return

    def main(self):
        """the main method"""
        self.window.mainloop()
        return

    def on_get_string(self, event = None):
        """open the string window"""
        prompt = PromptString() # a dialog which prompts for a string

        print str(prompt.string) # None
        prompt.main()
        print str(prompt.string)
        return

class PromptString:
    def __init__(self):
        """initialization"""
        self.string = None # the string

        # widgets

        self.window = Toplevel()

        self.input = Entry(self.window)
        self.input.bind("<Return>", self.on_set_string)

        set_button = Button(
            self.window,
            command = self.on_set_string,
            text = "Set"
            )

        # pack the widgets

        self.input.pack(side = LEFT)
        set_button.pack(side = RIGHT)
        return

    def main(self):
        """the main method"""
        self.window.mainloop() # execution pauses after this line finishes
        return

    def get_input(self):
        """get the input"""
        return self.input.get()

    def on_set_string(self, event = None):
        """set the string variable and close the window"""
        self.string = self.get_input()
        self.window.destroy()
        return

GUI().main()
```

It's eating me up that I can't solve this, but any help will be greatly appreciated, and I thank you in advance.

Edit:

I apologize for the confusion, but I actually reproduced the error this time, although it isn't so much an error as a problem.  The problem is that the *execution* of the program is halted in the `prompt.main()` call in line 39.  I tried clicking through and entered 2 subsequent values, which printed in reverse order **after** the `Tk` instance closed.  Is this paused execution a product of Tkinter?  How can I fix this?

EDIT 1:

The variable in question isn't global, but an attribute of the `PromptString` class.

Comment: Your code just runs and very quickly then quits. What are you expecting to see happen? By the time the after fires in `run_top`, 200ms will have elapsed and the `var.set` may not have been called before the program quits.

Comment: Paul Rooney is right. You can prove it by slowing thing down by changing the statement`tk.after(1000, run_top)` and `tk.after(2000, tk.destroy)` in the `run_tk()` function. After that your code will work. Also note the the `global var` doesn't do anything the the module level and can be left out.

Comment: If the code that you had posted wasn't correct, that's okay to change it, but to leave nothing doesn't help. You've now made my answer pointless and left no examples to look at and help you debug. Please see [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  In the meantime, I replicated and posted the issue in as concise a script as I could.  It is in Python 2.7.  It took longer to replicate than expected, but it's done.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as the question has completely changed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `Tk`'s `wait_window(other_window)` method.  This allows for the execution to not be halted by `Tkinter`'s execution structure.  The fixed code is below:

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        """initialization"""
        # widgets

        self.window = Tk()

        get_string = Button(
            self.window,
            command = self.on_get_string,
            text = "Open string"
            )

        # pack the widgets

        get_string.pack()
        return

    def main(self):
        """the main method"""
        self.window.mainloop()
        return

    def on_get_string(self, event = None):
        """open the string window"""
        prompt = PromptString() # a dialog which prompts for a string

        print str(prompt.string) # None
        prompt.wait(self.window) # wait for the prompt
        print str(prompt.string)
        return

class PromptString:
    def __init__(self):
        """initialization"""
        self.string = None # the string

        # widgets

        self.window = Toplevel()

        self.input = Entry(self.window)
        self.input.bind("<Return>", self.on_set_string)

        set_button = Button(
            self.window,
            command = self.on_set_string,
            text = "Set"
            )

        # pack the widgets

        self.input.pack(side = LEFT)
        set_button.pack(side = RIGHT)
        return

    def main(self):
        """the main method"""
        self.window.mainloop() # execution pauses after this line finishes
        return

    def get_input(self):
        """get the input"""
        return self.input.get()

    def on_set_string(self, event = None):
        """set the string variable and close the window"""
        self.string = self.get_input()
        self.window.destroy()
        return

    def wait(self, other_window):
        """run the window as an offshoot of another window"""
        other_window.wait_window(self.window)
        return

GUI().main()
```